# How to optimize a query that's running too slow (LEFT JOIN)

Tags: mysql, performance

My query is running too slow.....
any ways to speed it up?

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS a.*, b.*, c.*, d.*, e.*, f1.*, st6.* 
FROM tbl_a a 
LEFT JOIN tbl_b b ON a.m_id = b.m_id 
LEFT JOIN tbl_c c ON a.ms_id = c.ms_id 
LEFT JOIN tbl_d d ON a.gd_id = d.gd_id 
LEFT JOIN tbl_e e ON a.sd_id = e.sd_id 
LEFT JOIN tbl_f f1 ON a.tp_id = f1.tp_id 
LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT g.*, GROUP_CONCAT(f2.tp_name SEPARATOR ',') tp_name, f2.tp AS tp
            FROM tbl_g g
            LEFT JOIN tbl_f f2 ON g.tp_id = f2.tp_id 
            GROUP BY s_id 
        )st6 ON st6.s_id = a.s_id
```

Comment: Can you execute `EXPLAIN SELECT....`?

Comment: What you get for `explain select...` share the result into the question.

Comment: Try adding `EXPLAIN` or `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` keyword before your statement and see its output for possible hints, or if you are stuck with it, update the results to your question so we could help you more.

Comment: I am impressed by that query. Would you care to post this to the dailywtf. I'm sure many DBAs would like to have a looksee :)

Comment: `s.*` should be `a.*` - and using a super table like `a` and those sub tables will make very rare results of repeating rows of `a` that I think it will be meaningless - and I think your real problem of speed is inside of your inner select ;).

Comment: sorry,this is typing error..

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `LEFT` unless you have a specific reason for it.  I see no hint of such here.

A query like this is best optimized if it can perform the subquery *first*.  However, 'LEFT' is a hint that it cannot be.  Remove all the LEFTs and see if it is fast enough *and* gives the "right" answer.

Check to see that there is a `PRIMARY KEY` or `INDEX` on gd_id in both of the indicated tables in the following.  (And do likewise for other JOINs.)

```
JOIN tbl_d d ON a.gd_id = d.gd_id
```

If you still need help, provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.  And `EXPLAIN SELECT ...;`.